# WPF binding isn't working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to create a WPF `UserControl`. In my control I want to bind an `Image`'s `Source` to the `Source` property of my object.  Here's what I have so far:

**XAML file:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DeletableObjectPresenter.DeletableObjectPresenter" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="300" 
d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source}"></Image>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code:**

```
public ImageSource Source {
  get {
    return (ImageSource) GetValue(SourceProperty);
  }
  set {
    SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
  }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(DeletableObjectPresenter), new PropertyMetadata(new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DeletableObjectPresenter;component/Resources/StandartView.png",
            UriKind.Absolute))));
```

When I run project, I don't see the expected image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the source object of the binding, which is the UserControl itself here.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

Do not set the `DataContext` of the UserControl to itself, because that complicates using your UserControl in common binding scenarios, where it inherits the DataContext from its parent control:

```
<local:DeletableObjectPresenter Source"{Binding SomeImage}"/>
```

Here, `SomeImage` is a property in the inherited DataContext of the UserControl, which would not be so easily accessible if you had explicitly set the DataContext before.

---

Please note also that it is not necessary to the set an `UriKind` on a Pack URI:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri(
  "pack://application:,,,/DeletableObjectPresenter;component/Resources/StandartView.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not been set the `DataContext` attribute of your `UserControl`. Add 
`DataContext = {Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource Self}}`
 to your `UserControl`'s attributes.